# Dash app with Gunicorn doesn't start in Cloud Run

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, plotly-dash, gunicorn, google-cloud-run

I have a Python Dash app deployed in GCP Cloud Run for reporting and analysis. The app works as it does locally, and having it in GCR allows for multiple user access at the same time and implement some cloud solutions. What started happening is that, when multiple users access the app at the same time, performance and latency problems appear. I understand that Dash recommends using gunicorn with the app in order to do performance tuning and manage workers implementation. I have never used it, so I my knowledge is low.

Following some examples and documentation, I tried implementing it. It "didn't" look to complicated.

```
# Dash version 2.9.1
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server

app.layout = *app layout code*

*app callbacks code*

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run_server(host="0.0.0.0", port="8060")
```

Changed the Dockerfile app execution from:
`CMD ["python", "main.py"]`

To:
`CMD ["gunicorn", "-w", "3", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8060", "main:server"]`

The deploy to Cloud Run went well, no errors neither in Cloud Build nor Cloud Run. But looking into Cloud Run Logs, this is what it was written:
[Cloud Run Logs #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNYTR.png)
[Cloud Run Logs #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61fXJ.png)

An it goes on and on and on...

As far as I undestand, this is something to do with the min-instance in my GCR deployment (1 min instance) and Gunicorn shutting down and restarting (Is this correct?) Should this be avoid? Or is it okay? Does it consume resources in addition of the ones of the min-instance?

Another thing is that, in addition to those logs, I decided to test the app. But when accesing the DNS of the app, the browsers stays in the current page while loading to the app. No white page, no error, just the "loading" message on the tab name, thats it. I waited for 5 minutes but nothing. Before implementing Gunicorn, I was able to acccess the app immediately.

Does anyone know what is happening here? If I'm doing something wrong? (Which surely I am doing so)

Comment: Try increasing the timeout. Had this problem with a standard Python 3 App on Cloud Run (a few years back) and it only started 'responding' when I set the timeout to 0 (0 means infinite timeout i.e don't timeout)

Answer (score 0):

Was there a SIGTERM before the SIGKILL you showed in the logs? If yes, you can make your application handle that signal ([here's how](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/graceful-shutdowns-cloud-run-deep-dive)).

I don't think it's possible to have infinite timeout like someone suggested in the comments. Timeout value is set by default to 5 minutes and can be extended up to 60 minutes ([source](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout)).

I recommend that you check the memory usage of your service and update the limits accordingly. Here is the official [formula](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/memory-limits#optimizing) to help you with that.

Comment: There was no SIGTERM before the SIGKILL. The second picture is the continue of the first one. From there forward, is just a loop of the "Booting worker", "SIGKILL" and "WORKER TIMEOUT". I added the "timeout" and "threads" configuration, now it works. With one user in the app, the memory usage goes up to 60% (8 GiB limit) (Some tasks can process a large amount of data, but it's a rare case). Standing memory would be the amount consume by the app just being up, and the memory per request I can get it in the requestSize (The amount is in KiB or Bytes?) at the logs, right?

Comment: I believe you are talking about `httpRequest.requestSize` value in Logging. This is different from the memory per request value ([source](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas#cloud_run_limits)).

To calculate memory per request, you can do some profiling on your application to estimate how much each request is expected to need. Basically, it is something like this `(total memory usage in the service) / # of requests`